# Get images data and user data from facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping

I am working on a final year research project which is Intelligent Travel Recommending System. In this work I want use social media data to analyse what type people prefer what type places to travel.So I have to collect travel images posted by users in public and that user's data(age,nationlity,gender etc).I supposed analyse those images and categorize(natural,historical,hiking) them. Then I can recommend a place to a perticular user by using those categorized data and user data.So my problem is can I get those data from facebook now in 2020?

I've read some articles in internet and they've used graph API to acess data as a developer but the problem is fb no longer give acess to others data. If that's the case is there any other way to get public data?I mean can I scrape data from facebook or is there a better way?I am still a university student and I would be grateful if anyone can help me with this isse?

Answer (score 1):

Access to data of people who did not specifically authorize your App is not possible, no matter if public or not. Facebook specifically forbids scraping, so there is no way.
Also, you would not be allowed (or able to) contact specific users without their consent/approval.

I am afraid your idea would only work for people who autorize your App.

Comment: Then is it same for instagram and  twitter?

Comment: instagram is owned by facebook. but there is a general rule about data: if a user did not specifically approve usage of his data, it is none of your business. no matter if public or not.